# Java Object Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have been having a bit of an issue with creating an Array of Objects and then setting the variables for each object. I create the array and then loop through the array setting the variables but it seems each time I loop through it overwrites all previous variables.

It seems like a basic piece of code and a very irregular bug...

```
public class Test{

    Bubble[] bubble = new Bubble[2];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        bubble = new Bubble[2];

        bubble[0] = new Bubble();
        bubble[0].setDegree(360);

        bubble[1] = new Bubble();
        bubble[1].setDegree(180)

        System.out.println(bubble[0].printDegree());
        System.out.println(bubble[1].printDegree());
    }

}
```

That is the basics of it, the other class merely sets up variables and assigns values to them using "bubble[i].setDegree(int);"

The output of the progam gives me:

```
180
180
```

What I should be getting is:

```
360
180
```

I don't know if I am just rusty and missing something completely obvious or something is going terribly wrong.

Comment: Please show the definition of the class Bubble.

Comment: That's not your actual code - it wouldn't even compile at the moment, as you're trying to access an instance variable (`bubble`) from a static method.

Comment: Please post the Bubble class.

Comment: @captain: Please use proper words. `N y r` makes no sense to me, even as a native English speaker. I dread to think how incomprehensible it would be for someone who has English only as a second or third language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only possibility which I see is that your field *degree* in `Bubble` class is `static`. And since a static field is shared by all instances, whatever changes you do will be reflected for all the instances. Or your `setDegree()` or `printDegree()` method is broken (as pointed out by @JonSkeet in comments).

Comment: ...You were 30secs faster! :D

Comment: Could be setDegree() and printDegree() are using different instance variables and the default is 180.

Comment: @KennyTM. What do you mean by `default is 180`?

Comment: @RohitJain: `class Bubble { int mDegree = 180; ... }` (Well one case of what Jon Skeet said.)

Comment: @KennyTM. That will be the issue when the `setDegree` method is not actually doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @RohitJain: Yeah, e.g. maybe he defined the method as `void setDegree(int degree) { int mDegree = degree; }`.

Comment: Static was the issue. Thank you so much for your quick reply. It is greatly appreciated and has saved my soul... to an extent.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the variable in class bubble holding the value of degree is `static`, i. e. it exist per class and not per object.

You could also try that for clarification:

```
    bubble[0] = new Bubble();
    bubble[0].setDegree(360);

    System.out.println(bubble[0].printDegree());

    bubble[1] = new Bubble();
    bubble[1].setDegree(180)


    System.out.println(bubble[1].printDegree());
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems that static was causing an issue.

Comment: Np. Hope your question showed you the difference between static and non-static.

Comment: Sure did, it was something I was on the fence about, but now have a clearer understanding. Cheers.